# Django Reverse for 'authentication' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm working on a Django(1.10) project and I'm getting this error, it happens to me suddenly as it's working fine before.

> Reverse for 'authentication' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Here's my HTML template **slsDeployment.html**:

```
{% include 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<title> Serverless Deployment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.css' %}">


<style>
    .nav-link {
        color: white;
    }

a.nav-link.waves-light.active {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
.tooltipped{
    width: 24%;
}
#inline_index, #inline_package{
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
    background-attachment: local;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row total-content">
        {% include 'nav.html' %}
        <div class="col-md-9 content">
            <div class="world-map" style="width: 100%; margin-left:2%">
                <h3> Serverless Deployment :</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                {% if messages %}
                    <div class="container"
                     style="margin-top: 10%;padding-bottom: 0;background-color: #2F5671;margin-left: 2%;font-size:1.2em;color:ghostwhite; border-radius: 20px">
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tag }}" role="alert">
                                <strong>{% if message.tag == success %} Well done! {% else %}  Oh snap!
                                    </strong>{% endif %} {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                <br/>
            <form method="POST" id="slsForm" name="slsForm" class="form-horizontal" action=""
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10%;">
                        <br/><h5> Your selected project is: <b>{{ project }}</b></h5><br>
                        <label hidden for="project">Project </label>
                        <input type="text" name="project" id="project" value="{{ project }}" hidden/>
                     </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="fname" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">
                            Name:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname"
                               aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess1Status" required
                               placeholder="Enter cloud function name OR Deployment name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="fmemory" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">Memory
                        Allocated </label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="fmemory" id="fmemory">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Memory</option>
                            <option value="128"> 128 MB</option>
                            <option value="256"> 256 MB</option>
                            <option value="512"> 512 MB</option>
                            <option value="1024"> 1 GB</option>
                            <option value="2048"> 2 GB</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="code" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">Source Code
                        Option</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="codeOption" id="code" onchange="sco();">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>How you will Provide Code</option>
                            <option value="1">Inline Editor</option>
                            <option value="2">Zip Archive</option>
                            <option value="3">Clone Github Repo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="bucket" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">Storage
                        Bucket
                        </label>
                        {% if buckets %}
                            <select class="form-control" name="bucket" id="bucket" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected> Select your Storage Bucket</option>
                                {% for bucket in buckets %}
                                    <option value="{{ bucket.name }}"> {{ bucket.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                                    <option value=""><a href="https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/create-bucket?project={{ project }}">Create New Bucket</a></option>
                        </select>
                        {% else %}
                            <select class="form-control" name="bucket" id="bucket" required hidden></select>
                        <br>
                            <label><a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"
                                  href="https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project={{ project }}"><i
                                class="material-icons">add</i></a> <span><strong
                                style="font-size: 20px; vertical-align: middle;">Create a New Storage Bucket</strong> </span></label>
                    {% endif %}

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="entryPoint" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">
                        Function to Execute: <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltipped"  style="width: 45px;" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="It must be a valid function name otherwise your function will be failed."></i></label></div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="entryPoint" id="entryPoint"
                               aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess1Status" required
                               placeholder="Enter your function name"/>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="githubs" hidden style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">
                    <label class="control-label" for="sc_github" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;"> Github Repo
                        Url:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="url" class="form-control" name="sc_github" id="sc_github"
                               aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess1Status"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br> <br>
                <div class="form-group" hidden id="zipCode">
                    <label class="control-label" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: black;">Select File</label>
                    <input id="sourceFile" name="sourceFile" type="file" class="file" multiple
                           data-allowed-file-extensions='["zip"]'>
                    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text control-label" style="color:black; font-size: .9rem;">
                        Upload a Tar or Zip
                        archive which include Dockerfile, otherwise your deployment will fail.
                    </small>
                </div>
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <div class="col-lg-12" id="inlineEditor" hidden>
                    <div class="tabs-wrapper" disabled>
                        <ul class="nav classic-tabs tabs-cyan" role="tablist"
                            style="background-color: #1C445F; color: white;">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link waves-light active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel51" role="tab">index.js</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel52" role="tab">Package.json</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Tab panels -->
                    <div class="tab-content card form-group">
                        <!--Panel 1-->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="panel51" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="sc_inline_index" id="inline_index"
                                          aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess1Status" rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="panel52" role="tabpanel">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="sc_inline_package" id="inline_package"
                                          aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess1Status" rows="10" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="spinner" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07"></div>
                    <div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                        <div class="alert-message alert-message-success" id="message" hidden>
                            <h3>Congratulations!</h3>
                            <p>Your Function has been deployed
                                successfully!.</p>
                            <a id="trigger" target="_blank"> Click Here! </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" value="Submit"> Deploy
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                                id="project_btn"><a href="{% url 'users:selectDeployment' %}"
                                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: white;"> Go Back </a>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error is pointing to this line:

> In template /Users/abdul/Desktop/Projects/Updated_IGUI/IGui/dockerDep/templates/dockerDep/slsDeployment.html, error at line 0

Here's my urls.py:

```
url(r'^auth/', views.DockerAuth.as_view(), name='dockerAuth'),
url(r'^authGoogle/', views.GoogleAuthentication.as_view(), name='authGoogle'),
url(r'^authAws/', views.AwsAuthentication.as_view(), name='authAws'),
url(r'^selectProject/', views.SelectProject.as_view(), name='selectProject'),
url(r'^selectDeployment/', views.SelectDeployment.as_view(), name='selectDeployment'),
url(r'^selectContainer/', views.SelectContainer.as_view(), name='selectContainer'),
url(r'^dockerOptions/', views.SelectDockerOptions.as_view(), name='dockerOptions'),
url(r'^selectDeploymentSls/', views.SelectDeploymentSls.as_view(), name='selectDeploymentSls'),
url(r'^serverless/deployment/', ddviews.SlsDeployment.as_view(), name='slsDeployment'),
```

From views.py:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    project = request.session['project']
    # Get list of storage Buckets
    try:
        service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', http=views.getGoogleAuth(), cache_discovery=False)
        b_request = service.buckets().list(project=project)
        b_response = b_request.execute()
        buckets = b_response['items']
        print(buckets)
        return render(request, 'dockerDep/slsDeployment.html', {'project': project, 'buckets': buckets, })

    except:
        buckets = {}
        return render(request, 'dockerDep/slsDeployment.html', )
```

**Update:**  complete trackback

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 17, 2017 - 14:37:52
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'IGui.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[{'kind': 'storage#bucket', 'id': 'another-b', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/another-b', 'projectNumber': '446322245342', 'name': 'another-b', 'timeCreated': '2017-12-02T06:43:15.737Z', 'updated': '2017-12-02T06:43:15.737Z', 'metageneration': '1', 'location': 'US', 'storageClass': 'MULTI_REGIONAL', 'etag': 'CAE='}, {'kind': 'storage#bucket', 'id': 'brain-183103.appspot.com', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/brain-183103.appspot.com', 'projectNumber': '446322245342', 'name': 'brain-183103.appspot.com', 'timeCreated': '2017-10-16T06:20:15.914Z', 'updated': '2017-10-16T06:20:15.914Z', 'metageneration': '1', 'location': 'US', 'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 'etag': 'CAE='}, {'kind': 'storage#bucket', 'id': 'staging.brain-183103.appspot.com', 'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.brain-183103.appspot.com', 'projectNumber': '446322245342', 'name': 'staging.brain-183103.appspot.com', 'timeCreated': '2017-10-16T06:20:15.637Z', 'updated': '2017-10-16T06:20:15.637Z', 'metageneration': '1', 'location': 'US', 'lifecycle': {'rule': [{'action': {'type': 'Delete'}, 'condition': {'age': 15}}]}, 'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 'etag': 'CAE='}]
Internal Server Error: /user/deploy/serverless/deployment/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdul/Desktop/Projects/Updated_IGUI/IGui/dockerDep/ddviews.py", line 1606, in get
    return render(request, 'dockerDep/slsDeployment.html', {'project': project, 'buckets': buckets, })
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 210, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 439, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 392, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'authentication' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abdul/Desktop/Projects/Updated_IGUI/IGui/dockerDep/ddviews.py", line 1610, in get
    return render(request, 'dockerDep/slsDeployment.html', )
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 210, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 439, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/abdul/Documents/IVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 392, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'authentication' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
[17/Dec/2017 14:42:00] "GET /user/deploy/serverless/deployment/ HTTP/1.1" 500 268393
```

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post full traceback of the error?

Comment: see question update, please!

Comment: The error is not happening in the code you have shown, but in the base.html template, where you presumably have a call to `{% url "authentication" %}`.

Comment: Here's my **base.html** `{% load staticfiles %}{% load bootstrap3 %}
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' /><link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' /><link href="{% static 'css/dashboard.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script src="{% static 'js/tether.js' %}"></script><script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}"></head>`

Comment: @AbdulRehman There's no url pattern name `authentication` in your urls.